# Kubernetes pod /etc/resolv.conf has the wrong nameserver

Tags: kubernetes

I have a 4-node cluster setup at home that I am playing with, and ran into a problem when I started trying to do pod-to-pod communications.  I used Kubespray to install the nodes (1 "server/controller" and 3 "nodes").

The issue is that I can't resolve the services by name, only IP.  For instance, I used Helm to spin up Jeknins in the default namespace with the service name "jenkins", but if I try to ping "jenkins" or "jenkins.default" it doesn't resolve.  Doing `dig jenkins` or `dig jenkins.default` in a dnsutils pod produces:

```
/ # dig jenkins.default

; <<>> DiG 9.11.6-P1 <<>> jenkins.default
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 8927
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
; COOKIE: 229fbf94bb25564ae66dc8f45e7f646e5abb5f9dd4ede1d7 (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;jenkins.default.       IN  A

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 169.254.25.10#53(169.254.25.10)
;; WHEN: Sat Mar 28 14:51:26 UTC 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 72
```

Checking the `/etc/resolv.conf` file in the dnsutils pod, I noticed it had a strange IP address set for `nameserver`: 169.254.25.10.  After looking at all the pods, it seems they all have that same config, but the coredns service is set to 10.233.0.3.  In fact, all of the IPs are 10. something.  Manually changing `/etc/resolv.conf` on the dnsutils pod to use the 10.233.0.3 for the nameserver seemed to correct it for that pod, but how do I fix it for ALL pods? And where did that 169.254.25.10 IP come from anyhow?  My actual network DNS server is 10.0.0.5, and I have no 169.254 IPs in my internal network, as far as I know.

Comment: Have you looked in `/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml` and see what `clusterDNS:` is configured as? Because as far as I know, that's where the Pod's `resolv.conf` comes from, unless it is overridden in the `PodSpec`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As we can read from Kubernetes dosc [Customizing DNS Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-custom-nameservers/):

> If a Pod’s `dnsPolicy` is set to “`default`”, it inherits the name resolution configuration from the node that the Pod runs on. The Pod’s DNS resolution should behave the same as the node.
>
> If you don’t want this, or if you want a different DNS config for pods, you can use the kubelet’s  `--resolv-conf`  flag. Set this flag to “” to prevent Pods from inheriting DNS. Set it to a valid file path to specify a file other than  `/etc/resolv.conf`  for DNS inheritance.

As for [Pod’s DNS Policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pod-s-dns-policy) are as follows:

> DNS policies can be set on a per-pod basis. Currently Kubernetes supports the following pod-specific DNS policies. These policies are specified in the  `dnsPolicy`  field of a Pod Spec.
>
> - “`Default`“: The Pod inherits the name resolution configuration from the node that the pods run on. See  [related discussion](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-custom-nameservers/#inheriting-dns-from-the-node)  for more details.
> - “`ClusterFirst`“: Any DNS query that does not match the configured cluster domain suffix, such as “`www.kubernetes.io`”, is forwarded to the upstream nameserver inherited from the node. Cluster administrators may have extra stub-domain and upstream DNS servers configured. See  [related discussion](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-custom-nameservers/#impacts-on-pods)  for details on how DNS queries are handled in those cases.
> - “`ClusterFirstWithHostNet`“: For Pods running with hostNetwork, you should explicitly set its DNS policy “`ClusterFirstWithHostNet`”.
> - “`None`“: It allows a Pod to ignore DNS settings from the Kubernetes environment. All DNS settings are supposed to be provided using the  `dnsConfig`  field in the Pod Spec. See  [Pod’s DNS config](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pod-s-dns-config)  subsection below.

Comment: Thanks!  The trick was I had to edit the /var/lib/kubelets/config.yaml on each node and then restart the pods.

Answer (score 1):

169.254.0.0/16 is link local address. i mostly found this address get assigned when the link goes down. more info - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address.